# Trying to force a jQueryUI Tab to load with the load method.

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have three tabs loaded locally (not using AJAX).

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="1">tab1</a></li>
        <li><a href="2">tab2</a></li>
        <li><a href="3">tab3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
    $("#tabs").tabs()
</script>
```

After they load, I want to switch the second tab. I tried using the load method, like this, but it doesn't work.  Any idea how to do this?

```
$("#tabs").tabs("load",2);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ccgHS/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reference http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({ active: 1 });
```

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ccgHS/7/)**

your html like

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Some content.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Some content.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Some content.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ooooh, that seems to do the trick.  However, how come the tabs are all now filling with the list of tabs?  That shouldn't be happening..

Comment: However, when I use this in my actual program, it works excellently, so I'll be marking this as the correct answer.  Thanks!

Comment: because you set the html for header not for container tabs